# How do I save multiple copies of an image with different visible layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs3

I need to create multiple versions of an image with a different piece of artwork in each one. I created the image in Photoshop CS3 and added each version of the artwork as layers in a folder.

[image: Layers palette]

From this Photoshop document, I need to export one .png or .jpg for **each** of the layers in the 'Images' folder in the Layers palette, with only that layer visible (plus the other layers not in the Images folder). **How can I automate this process** so that I don't have to manually change the layer visibility and go *File > Save For Web* ten to fifteen times every time I tweak the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think layer comps might work for that.

http://www.photoshoplab.com/learning-layer-comps.html

Comment: Yup! After setting up a bunch of layer comps, I can do *File > Automation > Layer Comps to JPG...* and export them all in one batch.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked for you.

Comment: Whoops, actually the command was *File > Scripts > Layer Comps to Files...*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easy answer is to just record an Action of yourself saving all of the different layers (Actions window > Create New Action). Providing you're not renaming/deleting/adding layers, you should just be able to run that each time you make a tweak.

That's the only option you have, I believe. Sorry!